# How to implements Event Issuer in Android?

Tags: java, android, publish-subscribe

We have two different APIs to implement Issuer/Subscriber pattern in Java:

1) One from Java/Swing with `java.util.EventListener` and so on.

2) Another is from JavaFX with

Does Android provide/expect some third API or uses 1st?

Answer (score 0):

Default android behavior for some kind of Events is implemented in `LocalBroadcastManager` I think. For third party one you can go with GreenRobot's `EventBus`